# Error module.js:471 throw err; after updaing node.js

Tags: node.js, npm

I am getting following error after updating Node.js to 6.11.5

```
$ npm install
module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'buffer-shims'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Direcode\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:36:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Installing this module directly:

npm install buffer-shims

Comment: I tried that, but "npm install buffer-shims" also giving me same error...

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [the author](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/46938413/3), you can solve this issue by following these steps:

1. Uninstalling Node.js
2. Deleting the npm folder (`user/myuser/AppData/Roaming`)
3. Reïnstalling Node.js